# android signed apk App not installed if another app I've made is on phone

Tags: android, android-studio

I have 2 projects, and both are working fine. I can put them both on my phone with Android studio, but when I make a signed apk my new app will not install on a phone that has the old app. additional info:

- Application ids are different, and the same as the packagename
- application names also are different

The only thing I can think of is that that package name/applicationID for project1 is something like "w.x.y" and for project 2 it's something like "w.x.y.z". Could the fact that the package is a superset of the old package name cause this issue? And if not does anyone know what might be causing it?

Comment: Could you show your gradle file? Do you have productFlavors defined?

Comment: Not using flavors. actually have 2 separate projects, just one started a couple months ago as a copy of the other.

Comment: "w.x.y" and for project 2 it's something like "w.x.y.z" works fine for me. "Application ids are different": Where do you define it? manifest and/or gradle?

Comment: both, applicationID is defined in the gradle file, and package is defined in the manifest

Comment: Changed the applicationID and package structure of the second project to w.x.z and it works. Apparently android fails somehow from the superset app id.